# How to insert to db in payumoney android integration?

Tags: android, api, android-intent, payment-gateway, payumoney

This is my code :

```
public class PayUMoneyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Adding WebView as setContentView
     */
    WebView webView;

    /**
     * Context for Activity
     */
    Context activity;
    /**
     * Order Id
     * To Request for Updating Payment Status if Payment Successfully Done
     */
    int mId; //Getting from Previous Activity
    /**
     * Required Fields
     */
    // Test Variables
    /*
    private String mMerchantKey = "FCyqqZ";
    private String mSalt = "sfBpGA8E";
    private String mBaseURL = "https://test.payu.in";
    */

    // Final Variables
    private String mMerchantKey = "Your Merchant Key";
    private String mSalt = "Salt";
    private String mBaseURL = "https://secure.payu.in";


    private String mAction = ""; // For Final URL
    private String mTXNId; // This will create below randomly
    private String mHash; // This will create below randomly
    private String mProductInfo = "Food Items"; //Passing String only
    private String mFirstName; // From Previous Activity
    private String mEmailId; // From Previous Activity
    private double mAmount; // From Previous Activity
    private String mPhone; // From Previous Activity
    private String mServiceProvider = "payu_paisa";
    private String mSuccessUrl = "your success URL";
    private String mFailedUrl = "Your Failure URL";


    boolean isFromOrder;
    /**
     * Handler
     */
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /**
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    @SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
        * Setting WebView to Screen
        */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_for_payumoney);

        /**
         * Creating WebView
         */
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.payumoney_webview);

        /**
         * Context Variable
         */
        activity = getApplicationContext();

        /**
         * Actionbar Settings
         */
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_online_payment));

        /**
         * Getting Intent Variables...
         */
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {

            mFirstName = bundle.getString("name");
            mEmailId = bundle.getString("email");
            mAmount = bundle.getDouble("amount");
            mPhone = bundle.getString("phone");
            mId = bundle.getInt("id");
            isFromOrder = bundle.getBoolean("isFromOrder");

            Log.i(TAG, "" + mFirstName + " : " + mEmailId + " : " + mAmount + " : " + mPhone);

            /**
             * Creating Transaction Id
             */
            Random rand = new Random();
            String randomString = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()) + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
            mTXNId = hashCal("SHA-256", randomString).substring(0, 20);

            mAmount = new BigDecimal(mAmount).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

            /**
             * Creating Hash Key
             */
            mHash = hashCal("SHA-512", mMerchantKey + "|" +
                    mTXNId + "|" +
                    mAmount + "|" +
                    mProductInfo + "|" +
                    mFirstName + "|" +
                    mEmailId + "|||||||||||" +
                    mSalt);

            /**
             * Final Action URL...
             */
            mAction = mBaseURL.concat("/_payment");

            /**
             * WebView Client
             */
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                               SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "SSL Error! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    handler.proceed();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (url.equals(mSuccessUrl)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("status", true);
                        intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                        intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                        intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (url.equals(mFailedUrl)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("status", false);
                        intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                        intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                        intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(PayUMoneyActivity.this), "PayUMoney");

            /**
             * Mapping Compulsory Key Value Pairs
             */
            Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<>();

            mapParams.put("key", mMerchantKey);
            mapParams.put("txnid", mTXNId);
            mapParams.put("amount", String.valueOf(mAmount));
            mapParams.put("productinfo", mProductInfo);
            mapParams.put("firstname", mFirstName);
            mapParams.put("email", mEmailId);
            mapParams.put("phone", mPhone);
            mapParams.put("surl", mSuccessUrl);
            mapParams.put("furl", mFailedUrl);
            mapParams.put("hash", mHash);
            mapParams.put("service_provider", mServiceProvider);

            webViewClientPost(webView, mAction, mapParams.entrySet());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Posting Data on PayUMoney Site with Form
     *
     * @param webView
     * @param url
     * @param postData
     */
    public void webViewClientPost(WebView webView, String url,
                                  Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<html><head></head>");
        sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
        sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
            sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        }
        sb.append("</form></body></html>");

        Log.d("TAG", "webViewClientPost called: " + sb.toString());
        webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    /**
     * Hash Key Calculation
     *
     * @param type
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
    public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
        byte[] hashSequence = str.getBytes();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
            algorithm.reset();
            algorithm.update(hashSequence);
            byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1)
                    hexString.append("0");
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException NSAE) {
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onPressingBack();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onPressingBack();
    }

    /**
     * On Pressing Back
     * Giving Alert...
     */
    private void onPressingBack() {

        final Intent intent;

        if(isFromOrder)
            intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, ProductInCartList.class);
        else
            intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PayUMoneyActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you cancel this transaction?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    mHandler = null;
                    Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Payment Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The function onPageFinished() does not get invoked. The respective intent is not being called, when the payment succeeds. The webview just redirects to the success page. Can anyone help me in resolving this error? I also need to add the bundle variables to the db, on redirecting to success page.